# Why does my toggle icon functionality not work as intended?

Tags: javascript, css, function, icons

When I click on the icon to switch between an eye and an eye with a slash it doesn't respond immediately instead after two clicks and then after another click, the icon disappears. I don't understand why it is doing this so any help is welcome.

```js
const pass = document.getElementById("pass");
const togglePassword = document.getElementById("togglePass");
togglePassword.addEventListener("click", function Toggle() {

  if (pass.type === "password") {
    pass.type = "text";
    togglePassword.classList.toggle("fa-eye");
  } else {
    pass.type = "password";
    togglePassword.classList.toggle("fa-eye-slash");
  }
});
```

```css
.form-control i {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  right: 10px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.form-control i#togglePass {
  margin-left: -30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">

  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/c90e5c3147.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>-
  <title>Create an Account</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header">
      <h2>Create Account</h2>
    </div>
    <form class="form" action="register.php" method="POST" id="form" name="form">
      <div class="form-control">
        <label>Password</label>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Please enter a password" id="pass" name="pass">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-eye-slash" id="togglePass"></i>
        <small>Message</small>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>

  <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're toggling two different CSS-icon-classes conditionally.
I suggest you start from one icon, to understand what is going on...

Yet, here is your temp solution:

```
  if (pass.type === "password") {
    pass.type = "text";
    togglePassword.classList.remove("fa-eye-slash");
    togglePassword.classList.add("fa-eye");
  } else {
    pass.type = "password";
    togglePassword.classList.remove("fa-eye");
    togglePassword.classList.add("fa-eye-slash");
  }
```

(Instead of toggling on class, first remove unwanted, then add the other one)

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked and I understand how toggling it conditionally made the error arise